# VPN on SSID #2 (OpenWRT)

Tags: routing, openvpn, wireless-networking, openwrt

I am a new at openwrt (attitude adjustment - TP-Link WDR3600), I am trying to get an OpenVPN On Dedicated Wireless Access Point (VAP). Let me show you what I'm trying to do here with visuals:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/9rngqJJ.jpg]

- SSID Home is able to connect to VyprVPN as well, but unable to route to COMCAST.
  I manage to configure all parts, however my LAN bridge (clients) are still connecting through OpenVPN. It shouldn't be the case after I read through many tutorials/howtos. Here are my route print:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/F8b2mAC.jpg]

Here's the rules on my firewall so far:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/FJla7ZN.jpg]

I've configured it based on what limited knowledge I have with networking. I am an IT enthusiast and am willing to donate or help you if you require any help in enterprise technical support from software architect angle.

I hope you can help me shed some light on what else I'm missing.

I have been reading up a lot on the internet and found that it could be a routing issue. I have been sourcing around for help even from network gurus who has no idea what I'm trying to do.
Is there anybody out there who can help a little on this please?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem lies with the routing table. A VPN modifies the routing table: since the table is unique, a VPN modifies the routing table for anyone who is connected to your router.

However, Linux allows the possibility to have *multiple* routing tables, and to apply one of them depending on the properties of the LAN user: it is called *policy routing*. Luckily for you, OpenWRT does implement policy routing: you can find a description [here](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/networking/routing); even more luckily, it describes as an example exactly your case, *i.e.* a user wishing to route some LAN clients through a VPN, while leaving other clients outside the VPN.

For this to work, you will have to have users attached to *Home_VPN* to belong to a net different from those of *HOME*. For instance, you will have to instruct your dhcp program to give addresses in the range 192.168.51.0/24 to clients of HOME_VPN, and addresses in the range 192.168.77.0/24 to clients of the other wifi network. If you do so, the IP address of the router interface on HOME has to be 192.168.77.1, that on HOME_VPN must instead be 192.168.51.1.

You may then establish connectivity between the two separate networks by means of the following rules to add to the routing tables:

```
  ip route add 192.168.51.0/24 dev IF1
  ip route add 192.168.77.0/24 dev IF2
```

where IF1 and IF2 are then names of the wifi interfaces on the HOME_VPN and HOME wifi networks, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I believe "VPN and WAN Policy-Based Routing" (vpn-policy-routing) is now available on the OpenWRT software base.

After all interfaces are set, installing it and enabling its service without any special configuration should do the job. It shows on luci as a separate menu.

In my case, I created a VLAN and SSID for a VPN, totally separate network, with 2 new interfaces, one being the VPN (WAN) and the other being the separate local network.

I created their zones on firewall too. Used Wireguard as it appears to be lighter then other VPN protocols.

All working like a charm on an old Linksys e4200v2 with OpenWRT 19.07.3.