# VPN over separate instance OpenWRT

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, openvpn

I have been trying for a few days to get this going but so far I have not managed to.
My situation is pretty much like [VPN on SSID #2 (OpenWRT)](https://superuser.com/questions/805833/vpn-on-ssid-2-openwrt), however slightly different.

In my situation, I am using OpenVPN; I have a separate SSID for my 2,4ghz and 5ghz and a separate instance on 5ghz that should go through OpenVPN.

What I understand is that I need to look at IP routing but my networking knowledge is too limited to pull this off.

I run my "regular" instances on the IP range 192.168.1.x.
The instance that should go through the VPN is at 192.168.55.x.

On the answer at the comparing question I tried

```
ip route add 192.168.55.0/24 dev tun0
```

but this gives me an error:

```
Cannot find device "tun0"
```

Obviously tun0 is the OpenVPN.

I literally have no clue how to solve this or in what direction I need to go.
Perhaps someone can help me pull this off.

Edit:
I have tried the steps from [Routing a particular subnet into a VPN tunnel](https://superuser.com/questions/887745/routing-a-particular-subnet-into-a-vpn-tunnel?rq=1) this can be seen on the OpenVPN config as well, without success though.

My config files:

**/etc/config/network**

```
config interface 'loopback'
    option ifname 'lo'
    option proto 'static'
    option ipaddr '127.0.0.1'
    option netmask '255.0.0.0'

config globals 'globals'
    option ula_prefix 'fd15:4503:4ed4::/48'

config interface 'lan'
    option ifname 'eth1'
    option force_link '1'
    option type 'bridge'
    option proto 'static'
    option ipaddr '192.168.1.1'
    option netmask '255.255.255.0'
    option ip6assign '60'

config interface 'wan'
    option ifname 'eth0'
    option proto 'dhcp'

config interface 'wan6'
    option ifname 'eth0'
    option proto 'dhcpv6'

config switch
    option name 'switch0'
    option reset '1'
    option enable_vlan '1'

config switch_vlan
    option device 'switch0'
    option vlan '1'
    option ports '0 2 3 4 5'

config switch_vlan
    option device 'switch0'
    option vlan '2'
    option ports '1 6'

config interface 'VPN'
    option proto 'none'
    option ifname 'tun0'

config interface 'OVPN'
    option _orig_ifname 'wlan0-1'
    option _orig_bridge 'false'
    option proto 'static'
    option ipaddr '192.168.55.1'
    option netmask '255.255.255.0'
```

So far I use this to connect to OpenVPN.

**/etc/openvpn/client.ovpn**

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
port 1194
remote 108.61.152.187
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca /etc/openvpn/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/client.crt
key /etc/openvpn/client.key
auth-user-pass ./pass.txt
ns-cert-type server
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
verb 3
#Prevents default gateway from being set on the default routing table
route-noexec
#Allows route-up script to be executed
script-security 2
#Calls custom shell script after connection to add necessary routes
route-up /etc/openvpn/route-up.sh
```

**/etc/config/wireless**

```
config wifi-device 'radio0'
    option type 'mac80211'
    option hwmode '11a'
    option path 'pci0000:01/0000:01:00.0'
    option country '00'
    option htmode 'VHT80'
    option channel '157'
    option txpower '30'

config wifi-iface
    option device 'radio0'
    option network 'lan'
    option mode 'ap'
    option ssid 'TP-Link 5G'
    option encryption 'psk2'
    option key 'key'

config wifi-device 'radio1'
    option type 'mac80211'
    option channel '5'
    option hwmode '11n'
    option path 'platform/qca955x_wmac'
    option htmode 'HT40'
    option txpower '30'
    option country '00'

config wifi-iface
    option device 'radio1'
    option network 'lan'
    option mode 'ap'
    option ssid 'TP-Link'
    option encryption 'psk-mixed+ccmp'
    option key 'key'

config wifi-iface
    option device 'radio0'
    option mode 'ap'
    option ssid 'TP-Link VPN'
    option network 'OVPN'
    option encryption 'psk2'
    option key 'key'
```

**route-up.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

#Clear all routes on vpn routing table (this is to make sure there isn't any crap left over from a previous vpn connection
ip route flush table vpn

#Copy routing table from main routing table into vpn table
ip route show table main | grep -Ev ^default | while read ROUTE ; do ip route add table vpn $ROUTE; done

#Add default gateway to vpn routing table
ip route add default via ${route_vpn_gateway} dev ${dev} table vpn
```

Results of **Ifconfig**

```
6rd-wan_6rd Link encap:IPv6-in-IPv4
          inet6 addr: ::77.174.30.80/96 Scope:Compat
          inet6 addr: 2001:838:ad1e:5000::1/40 Scope:Global
          UP RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1280  Metric:1
          RX packets:256964 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:160291 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:284886943 (271.6 MiB)  TX bytes:18047017 (17.2 MiB)

br-lan    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr E8:DE:27:F5:E7:F6
          inet addr:192.168.1.1  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2001:838:ad1e:5000::1/60 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::eade:27ff:fef5:e7f6/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: fd15:4503:4ed4::1/60 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:19173187 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13930435 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:21346350453 (19.8 GiB)  TX bytes:19757831552 (18.4 GiB)

br-lan:1  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr E8:DE:27:F5:E7:F6
          inet addr:10.3.5.3  Bcast:10.255.255.255  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr E8:DE:27:F5:E7:F7
          inet addr:77.174.30.80  Bcast:77.174.31.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::eade:27ff:fef5:e7f7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7978235 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:2 frame:0
          TX packets:3747223 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:3172877058 (2.9 GiB)  TX bytes:259141128 (247.1 MiB)
          Interrupt:4

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr E8:DE:27:F5:E7:F6
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5749 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:21872 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:968857 (946.1 KiB)  TX bytes:4234774 (4.0 MiB)
          Interrupt:5

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1389 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1389 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:108498 (105.9 KiB)  TX bytes:108498 (105.9 KiB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00                                                                                        -00
          inet addr:10.8.0.22  P-t-P:10.8.0.21  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr E8:DE:27:F5:E7:F4
          inet6 addr: fe80::eade:27ff:fef5:e7f4/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1398316 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5616658 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:116548785 (111.1 MiB)  TX bytes:3907071356 (3.6 GiB)

wlan0-1   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr EA:DE:27:F5:E7:F4
          inet addr:192.168.55.1  Bcast:192.168.55.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::e8de:27ff:fef5:e7f4/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:1944 (1.8 KiB)

wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr E8:DE:27:F5:E7:F5
          inet6 addr: fe80::eade:27ff:fef5:e7f5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:17805065 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8380514 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:32356101 (30.8 MiB)  TX bytes:3263563261 (3.0 GiB)
```

Comment: To make traffic go different routes based on which interface(/WiFi network) it comes from, you need policy routing. /edit: It seems you already found out the part about multiple routing tables, but you’re missing rules that make use of these.